# How to collect garbage with an empty hand?

Tags: exploding-kittens

In exploding kittens there’s one card left in the pile an exploding kitten. player one has no cards left in their hand after playing an attack card. player two plays a garbage collection card. player one has no card to put into the garbage collection do they forfeit the game?

Comment: When making a title you need to describe your question not just put the name of the game in.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from [the rules](https://www.explodingkittens.com/pages/rules-streaking-kittens):

> Garbage Collection 1 Card
>
> Every player **who has cards** (including the player who played this card)
> must choose 1 card from their hand to secretly insert into the Draw
> Pile. Then, shuffle the entire Draw Pile.

You only have to put a card on the deck if you have any in your hands.

So player two plays garbage collection and everybody who is able puts a card on the deck and it is shuffled. Then player two still has to finish their turn.